# Quarkus Kafka Consumner not connecting

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

I am trying to build a Kafka Consumer with Quarkus. Sadly I don't seem to get it working.

This is my application.properties:

```
#Kafka settings
kafka.bootstrap.servers=servers name
kafka.group.id=my specialized group id

kafka.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
kafka.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
security.protocol=sasl_ssl
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.username=username
sasl.password=password

#first topic settings
mp.messaging.incoming.first-topic.topic=topic name
mp.messaging.incoming.first-topic.connector=smallrye-kafka

#second topic settings
mp.messaging.incoming.second-topic.topic=topic name
mp.messaging.incoming.second-topic.connector=smallrye-kafka

#Processing all messages (for test purposes)
%dev.mp.messaging.incoming.first-topic.auto.offset.reset=earliest
%dev.mp.messaging.incoming.second-topic.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

This is what my Java class looks like:

```
@Path("someName")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApplicationScoped
public class IpsiConnectorResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(IpsiConnectorResource.class.getName());

    @Connector("first-topic")
    @Incoming("first-topic")
    @Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.POST_PROCESSING)
    public CompletionStage<Void> processFirstTopicMessage(final Message<byte[]> message) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("message received: " + message.getPayload().toString());
        return message.ack();
    }
    
    @Connector("second-topic")
    @Incoming("second-topic")
    @Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.POST_PROCESSING)
    public CompletionStage<Void> processSecondTopicMessage(final Message<byte[]> message) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("message received: " + message.getPayload().toString());
        return message.ack();
    }
}
```

The error message looks something like this:

```
 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-second-topic, groupId=my sepcialized group id] Bootstrap broker servers name (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-first-topic, groupId=my sepcialized group id] Bootstrap broker servers name (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I changed some of the namings to protect my data.

Does someone have any experience in this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: For anyone wondering the solution was: the security.protocol has to be SASL_SSL in upper case

Comment: Please post answers below rather than as comments